# Why would PHP's REQUEST and GET suddenly cease working?

Tags: php, post

I have a site on a shared server. The contact form suddenly stopped working a few days ago. I ran a test, stripped it back to basics but it seems that PHP's `post` method has stopped working.

I made a very simple form on one page:

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" class="form">
    <label for="name">
        Name:
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <div class="form-buttons">
        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

and simply put the following PHP on the process page:

```
echo "Name: " . $_REQUEST['name'];
```

But nothing happens. The Name value does not come through.

I've tried `$_GET['name']` and `method="GET"` with no luck.

In Chrome Inspector's Network tab I see the form data being passed correctly. It's like the PHP just isn't picking it up.

Would anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you checked any logs on the server?

Comment: Sadly don't have access to the server - joys of freelance!

Comment: So make a test case, put that code into something locally, post to itself, check if it does what it is supposed to do. Then you can scratch your head and ask yourself if its PHP still I suppose.

Comment: Does `process.php` have the appropriate PHP opening tag, ie `<?php`? Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the script

Comment: What exactly do you see? Do you see the `Name:` part or just a completely blank page? What do you see if you right-click and select _View page source_?

Comment: Are you sure PHP is enabled on your server?

Comment: @Phil I do see the Name string echoed. All other PHP on the page works (in fact with the form's complete script it still sends the email, just with no data in it.

Comment: You might find an answer in here ~ https://serverfault.com/questions/171047/why-is-php-request-array-empty. Do you know if the server moved from Apache to NGINX recently?